nextjs iOS SecurityError: The operation is insecure
I have sentry on my nextjs app and I have the following error SecurityError: The operation is insecure. on some customer coming on my website using iOS.
This is the only clue I have
And seems that it cause nextjs to crash because after that I have A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
